# C Segmentation Fault in strcmp for-loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcmp

Novice programmer learning C, I'm encountering this 'segmentation fault (core dumped)' error while trying to run a for-loop with strcmp. I have seen questions on similar issues with strcmp, but they don't seem to address my problem. Here's the program I've written.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
  char ftpstring[15];
  printf("\nEnter valid ftp command > ");
  fgets(ftpstring,15,stdin);

  const char* ftp[] = { "ascii", "recv", "send", "rmdir", "mkdir" , "pwd", "ls", "cd", "status", "quit" };

  for ( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ ) {
    int comparison;
    comparison = strcmp(ftpstring, ftp[i]);
    if (comparison == 0 ) {
      printf("%s is a valid ftp command.", ftpstring);
      break;
    }
    if(i == 10) {
      printf("%s is NOT a valid ftp command.", ftpstring);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, this program tries to read user input to determine if it matches one of the predefined valid ftp commands, then return whether or not it does.

Comment: `for ( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )` should be `for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )`

Answer (score 1):

`for ( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )` should be `for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )`

The `ftp` array contains 10 strings, so the loop should be from `0` to `9` including.

More general solution could be

```
for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof(ftp)/sizeof(ftp[0]); i++ )
```

But it is better to define a macro

```
#define FTP_NUM_OF_COMMANDS 10
```

and define the `ftp` array as following:

```
const char* ftp[FTP_NUM_OF_COMMANDS] = { "ascii", "recv", "send", "rmdir", "mkdir" , "pwd", "ls", "cd", "status", "quit" };
```

In this case the compiler will also verify that you don't initialize it (by mistake) with more than 10 values. The `for` loop will look like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < FTP_NUM_OF_COMMANDS; i++ )
```

Also note that the following code should be moved outside the `for` loop

```
if(i == FTP_NUM_OF_COMMANDS) {
  printf("%s is NOT a valid ftp command.", ftpstring);
}
```

`i==FTP_NUM_OF_COMMANDS` will never occur inside the loop itself, if that condition is `true`, the `for` loop should break. Make sure that you define `i` outside the `for` loop scope so it would be available after the `for` loop breaks.

Comment: Even better would be to do `sizeof(ftp)/sizeof(ftp[0])` -- because then you can change the size or type of elements in `ftp` without causing a bug if you don't notice this line.

Comment: @gilez Agree! Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Just to say, i rather write `for (int i = 0; ftp[i] != NULL; i++)`

Comment: @ale-batt It would be a mistake. Nothing guarantees that `ftp [10]` will always be 0 (`NULL`).

Comment: You're right, it's just i used to NULL-ended my array

Answer (score 0):

You are making a comparison past the end of the array: the `for` loop should stop at 9, while yours goes past the end of the array.

Using 10 as a "magic number" is not a good choice, either: it is much better to have the [compiler compute the size for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10349610/335858). Finally, it is better to use index *after* the loop to decide if the command has been found or not:

```
int index = -1;
for ( int i = 0 ; i != sizeof(ftp) / sizeof(*ftp) ; i++ ) {
    if (!strcmp(ftpstring, ftp[i])) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (index == -1) {
    printf("%s is NOT a valid ftp command.", ftpstring);
}
```